# Resizing image with ImageMagick and CloudConvert

Tags: imagemagick, cloudconvert

I'm trying to upload image to CloudConvert, convert it to PNG and resize it with ImageMagick.

```js
import CloudConvert from 'cloudconvert';

const cloudConvert = new CloudConvert('api_key');

let job = await cloudConvert.jobs.create({
    "tasks": {
        "upload_thumbnail": {
            "operation": "import/upload"
        },
        "convert_thumbnail": {
            "operation": "convert",
            "input": [
                "upload_thumbnail"
            ],
            "output_format": "png",
            "filename": "thumbnail.png"
        },
        "resize_2x_thumbnail": {
            "operation": "command",
            "engine": "imagemagick",
            "input": [
                "convert_thumbnail"
            ],
            "command": "convert",
            "arguments": "{INPUTFILE} -resize 330x330 {OUTPUTFILE}",
            "engine_version": "7.0.9"
        }
    }
});
```

I'm trying it in snadbox, the file is uploaded correctly, converted to png, but resize returns:
`ERROR UNKNOWN_ERROR convert: no images defined '{OUTPUTFILE}' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3273.  upload_thumbnail     import/upload  FINISHED`

As there is no example or documentation how to pass parameters to the command, I'm stucked.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In API v2, you need to specify paths like this:

```
"arguments": "/input/convert_thumbnail/thumbnail.png -resize 330x330 /output/thumbnail.png"
```

Comment: Some documentation that may be helpful is available here: https://cloudconvert.com/api/v2/command#command-tasks